# How to keep popup remains open in mapbox-gl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

var geojson = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [-77.032, 38.913]
},
"properties": {
"title": "Mapbox",
"description": "Washington, D.C."
}
},
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [-122.414, 37.776]
},
"properties": {
"title": "Mapbox",
"description": "San Francisco, California"
}
}]
};

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
center: [-96, 37.8],
zoom: 3
});

// add markers to map

geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

```
// create a HTML element for each feature
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';

// make a marker for each feature and add it to the map
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: 25}) // add popups
        .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
    .addTo(map);
```

});